# How to obtain the lower bar with the applications

Tags: .desktop, taskbar

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 in VMware Workstation 12 and I don't know how to obtain the bar with the applications shown in the following figure

[image]

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.